# how can I achieve this randomly arranged images kind look?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I came across this page https://pepecph.com/ and thought the effect where pictures just show up randomly on the screen was pretty cool.

I wonder what are some ways to achieve this effect. Should we divide the screen using css grid and assign some of the grid items to be the image elements? I am not good at css and I hope someone can give me some examples to show this is possible.

Comment: They just do it using the css property `z-index` when you hover the label, the `z-index ` property is increased by one. So the image comes forward.

Comment: @DaniloScavassa hi I know how z-index works and I think it has nothing to do with the effect I asked about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to generate random numbers for positioning images. You can apply the below CSS to decide position:

```
position:absolute; top: x px; left: y px;
```

From Javascript generate `x` and `y` using a random number generator. Then position each image within a `div` container and apply CSS.

Here is sample code that randomly positions images in the page. 
**Logic can be added to this to ensure images do not overlap.**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
<script>
    images = ['airplane.png', 'boat.png', 'fruits.png', 'tulips.png', 'pool.png']
    $(document).ready(() => {
        images.forEach((image, index) => {
            var img = $('<img width="100px" height="100px" id="img-' + index + '" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/' + image + '">');
            img.attr('style', 'position:absolute;top:' + getRandomNumber() + 'px;left:' + getRandomNumber() + 'px');
            img.appendTo('#main');
        });
        function getRandomNumber() {
            return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 600);
        }
    });
</script>
```